# Overriding onNewToken and getting tokens from firebase errors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to retrieve my token and i'm doing exactly as many examples says
On **FirebaseMessagingService** i have this

```
 @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.e("Refreshed token:",token);
    }
```

And i got the **error**

> Method does not override method from it's superclass

and of course the `super.onNewToken(token)` has the **error**

> cannot resolve method

On my **mainactivity** i have this inside **OnCreate()**

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {          
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();    
     }
 });
```

And the errors i get are:

> > Cannot resolve getInstanceId()
>
> Cannot resolve InstanceIdResult
>
> cannot
>   resolve getToken()
>
> and Method does not override method from it's
>
> > superclass

**Update**

Class declaration

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.e("Refreshed token:",token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

**Update v2**

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.iid.zzb {
    private static final java.util.Queue<java.lang.String> zzoma;

    public FirebaseMessagingService() { /* compiled code */ }

    @android.support.annotation.WorkerThread
    public void onMessageReceived(com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { /* compiled code */ }

    @android.support.annotation.WorkerThread
    public void onDeletedMessages() { /* compiled code */ }

    @android.support.annotation.WorkerThread
    public void onMessageSent(java.lang.String s) { /* compiled code */ }

    @android.support.annotation.WorkerThread
    public void onSendError(java.lang.String s, java.lang.Exception e) { /* compiled code */ }

    @com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide
    protected final android.content.Intent zzp(android.content.Intent intent) { /* compiled code */ }

    @com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide
    public final boolean zzq(android.content.Intent intent) { /* compiled code */ }

    @com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide
    public final void handleIntent(android.content.Intent intent) { /* compiled code */ }

    static void zzr(android.os.Bundle bundle) { /* compiled code */ }

    static boolean zzal(android.os.Bundle bundle) { /* compiled code */ }
```

Comment: Make sure you are using latest `dependencies` of `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: show the class declaration, where you wrote `class yourclass extends FirebaseMessagingService`

Comment: @NileshRathod i have implemented the latest ones!

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko check the updated post

Comment: looks weird. Can you also show the dependancies? (the firebase one at least)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko check the dependancies!I know it's weird!!!

Comment: can you check inside the `FirebaseMessagingService` class what is the signature of `onNewToken` method? CTRL+Click on the `FirebaseMessagingService` in your code to open it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko when i press ctrl-click it says no usages found in all places

Comment: oh, if you are using a MacOS, then it should be command + click

Comment: It's windows check the photo of the post

Comment: `CTRL+Click on the FirebaseMessagingService`, not on the `onNewToken`

Comment: @AlexKolydas you code is working fine for me have u tried **`Clean-ReBuild`** or `Invalidate-cache and restart android studio`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko sorry i'm stupid :P check the second update

Comment: @NileshRathod yeap nothing happened :/

Comment: as you see, this class is really missing the `onNewToken` method. I have no idea why unfortunately. I'd suggest you to re-download the dependencies.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you very much for your time!i will see what i can do!

Comment: I have the same problem, can you tell me how you resolved it please?

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle (app):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

extend class:

```
package /*package name*/;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is also called
     * when the Instance ID token is initially generated, so this is where
     * you retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d("TAG", "New token: " + token);
        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token); //As I understand it, you need to implement it yourself.
    }
}
```

in tag  in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFcmListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Add to your activity where you want to get a token:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
       }
    });
```

Comment: There is an error with `getApplication ()` for the code below. Do you know how to handle it? `private void sendRegistrationToServer(@Nullable String token) {
        if (token != null) {
            ((SubApp) getApplication()).getRepository().registerInstanceId(token);
            // No need to unregister the previous Instance ID token because the server
            // automatically removes invalidated tokens.
        }
    }`

Comment: And still: `Method doesn't override method from its superclass`. I am working on classytaxijava that I get these errors